# Socket.io communicates in oner direction only

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to get Socket.io to work. My code is below. I get the "Welcome to Socket.io." when I visit

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

but that is all I get. app.js looks like it will send back a message but I get nothing in my Javascript console and nothing on the page except "Welcome to Socket.io.". I tried visiting

```
http://localhost/chat
```

and

```
http://localhost/news
```

and it is the same results. I want to test a two way communication using Socket.io. Will this script do that for me and is a firewall possibly blocking the return message. This is an example for Socket.ip V0.9 page.

```
// app.js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

var chat = io
   .of('/chat')
   .on('connection', function (socket) {
       socket.emit('a message', {
          that: 'only',
         '/chat': 'will get'
    });
    chat.emit('a message', {
    everyone: 'in'
  , '/chat': 'will get'
  });
});

var news = io
  .of('/news')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('item', { news: 'item' });
});
```

The index.html

```
//index.html
<script>
var chat = io.connect('http://localhost/chat')
  , news = io.connect('http://localhost/news');

chat.on('connect', function () {
  chat.emit('hi!');
});

news.on('news', function () {
  news.emit('woot');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are trying to use socket.io like http server. You cannot transmit data like html pages. You can send data, but you need javascript/jquery to process the sent data to be able to see it. Try putting `alert('hi!');` inside chat on connect in index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Oh. Interesting. It does not look like you have a server even running, just io.

//app.js
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
/* place index.html in /public */
var port = process.env.PORT || 5050;

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
  log : false
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket.on('hi', function(data) {
console.log('yay');
socket.emit('hello');
});
});
server.listen(port);

//for index.html do the same.

chat.on('connect', function () {
  chat.emit('hi');
});
chat.on('hello',function(){
console.log('yay got hello');
}):
```

// 
I am just beginning on stackoverflow. Not that great at explaining. I am using express here because it is simplier. If this does not work, give me what version of node, express, and socket.io you are using. Also, I have not used namespaces yet for socket.io, so this could be a problem.

Comment: I added it and it did not help. When I go View Page Source all I get is "Welcome to Socket.io." There is no html or javascript just Welcome to Socket.io. Maybe this is a firewall issue. Does socket.io communicate on some other port other than 80?

Comment: I changed my answer. I', trying to figure out how to use stack overflow the best. I hope this helps.